# let in lookup whit objectId

Tags: mongodb, aggregate

I want to use some `ObjectId` in my `let` but i have the same error every time :

```
Failed to execute script.

Error: invalid object id: length 
Details:
@(shell):6:36
```

My query :

```js
db.projects.aggregate([
    {$lookup: {
        from: 'pointValueChangements',
        let: {id: '$_id'},
        pipeline: [
            { $match: { projectId: new ObjectId('$$id'), date: {$lte: new Date()}}},
            { $sort: { date: -1}},
            { $limit: 1},
        ],
        as: 'pointValue',
    }},
    {$project: {pointValue: 1}}
])
```

If i replace `new ObjectId('$$id')` by `'$$id'` the query work but the result is not good.

If i replace `'$$id'` by `ObjectId(someMongoId)` all is ok (but is not good because this id match only for one row...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Try this query

   db.projects.aggregate([
    {$lookup: {
        from: 'pointValueChangements',
        let: {id: '$_id'},
        pipeline: [
            { $match: { 
                 $expr:
                    {
                      $and:
                       [
                         { $eq: ['$projectId', '$$id'] },
                         { date: {$lte: new Date() }},
                       ],
                    },
               }},
            { $sort: { date: -1}},
            { $limit: 1},
        ],
        as: 'pointValue',
    }},
    {$project: {pointValue: 1}}
])
```

Comment: Please use this query